# Linear regression - testing for multicolinearity in the presence of heteroskedasticty in Eviews

Tags: eviews

My question concerns use of VIF test for multicolinearity diagnostics when the model suffers from heteroskedasticity.

I want to use HAC correction to account for heteroskedasticity in my model. However VIF gives my starkly different results depending if I run it after estimating the model with simple OLS without error correction, compared to when I start with regression with HAC applied and then run VIF. I use Eviews.

For me it was surprising as the test statistic in VIF is just an 1/(1-R^2) where R^2 is calculated for a model in which given x_i variable is regressed against the rest of X variables. This implies that the result should not depend on standard errors of the estimated parameters in our original y against X regression, and thus should not depend on whether I use robust errors or not.

However, in Eviews VIF is calculted differently and estimates of standard errors for parameters are used ([tutorial](https://www3.nd.edu/~nmark/FinancialEconometrics/EViews10_Manuals/EViews%2010%20Users%20Guide%20II.pdf), pp. 198 of the pdf). While it is suggested that both approaches are equivalent, clearly is not the case in my example.

In short, in which order should I proceed - first test for multicolinearity with simple OLS model and then move on to model with HAC, or the other way - estimate the model with HAC and then run VIF?
Thanks for all your help!